# How to write a 2D list with increasing numbers using a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, 2d

I can write a 2d list using for loops with the same value inside like:

```
list = [[0 for x in range(4)] for y in range(4)]
```

and I get the result:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

But how can i write something similar to get a result incrementing the numbers?

The output should be something like:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Those are not loops, they are list comprehensions. If you have trouble writing a nested list comprehension, the normal approach is to write it first as nested loops. Then convert the code to comprehensions, if it can be done readably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
cols = 4
rows = 4
[[x+y*cols for x in range(cols)] for y in range(rows)]
```

Or, using [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
import numpy as np
rows = 3
cols = 5
np.arange(rows*cols).reshape((rows, cols)).tolist()
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this list comprehension:

```
L = [[x for x in range(y,y+4)] for y in range(0,16,4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this :

```
l = [[x + 3*y +y  for x in range(4)] for y in range(4)]
```